# NEXT API Middleware not able to parse request body returns null

Tags: next.js

I have created a middleware as `pages/api/open/_middleware.ts`. Here's the code:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // create an instance of the class to access the public methods. This uses `next()`,
  // you could use `redirect()` or `rewrite()` as well
  console.log(
    request.method,
    request.body,
    request.headers.get('Authorization')
  );

  let response = NextResponse.next();
  // get the cookies from the request
  if (request.method === 'GET')
    return NextResponse.json({ name: 'UnAuthenticated' });
  return response;
}
```

I tried to make request from `VSCode Http Client`, `Postman` and `Python` too. But in all cases the request.body is consoled as null:

VSCode Client:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/open HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept: application/json

{
  "name": "My First Project",
  "description": "This is my first project",
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/open"
}
```

Postman Client:
[image]

Python Requests module:

```
>>> from requests import post
>>> post("http://localhost:3000/api/open",json={"a":1})
<Response [200]>
>>> headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
>>> post("http://localhost:3000/api/open",json={"a":1},headers=headers)
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

But all of this print null in console:

```
event - compiled successfully in 60 ms (151 modules)
POST null xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Headers are parsed correctly but the body never gets parsed even after specifying content-type.

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here? Aren't middleware supposed to intercept the request body?

Answer (score 1):

I think the request object is an extension of the Fetch API Request interface. To read the body you can use the `json` method directly on the request object, which returns a promise which "resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON":
`await request.json()`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/json

Seeing that you are reading the body in middleware, you may want to consider using the `.clone()` method so you don't remove the body from the original request object.